# criar botão para cancelar função fullscreen

Tags: javascript

Quero criar um botão para cancelar um evento/função fullscreen sem função toogle 
apenas clicar no botão e fechar o modo tela cheia.

alguém pode me ajudar  ?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema com o **JavaScript**

**Solução:**

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>


function exitFullscreen() {

        if(document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen(); }

        else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();}

        else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
    </script>



html:

    <button class="fechar" onclick="exitFullscreen();"> X </button>
```

Comment: Só salientando que o uso do `jQuery` é opcional.

Comment: Obrigado,  @Valdeir Psr , sou novo estava tentando deixar os códigos visíveis. Como adiciono demonstração ?

Comment: Basta selecionar todo o código e apertar `Ctrl + K`

Comment: não funcionou, fiz como voce disse

Comment: Você **deve** selecionar apenas o código. Ou você pode inserir 4 espaços em cada linha; ou ainda poderá clicar no ícone `{}`